# Two questions about this sentence: 1. Why not "hearts"? 2. Which aforementioned action does "as Oliver did" refer to?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> His classic tale of a poor orphan boy strikes at the **heart** of all those who have ever wanted "more", **as Oliver did**.

Two questions about this sentence:

1. Why not "hearts",since it says "of all those..."?
2. Which aforementioned action does "as Oliver did" refer to, "strikes" or "have ever wanted more"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > His classic tale of a poor orphan boy strikes at the **heart** of all those who have ever wanted "more", **as Oliver did**.

Note: this sentence appears in [an article](http://elt.i21st.cn/article/5370_1.html) from [i21st](http://www.i21st.cn/), which is a Chinese website. The author of the article, and thus the sentence in question, is not a native English speaker. There are grammatical, spelling and other errors throughout the article. One might question the wisdom of relying on such a source if one wants to learn correct contemporary English.

> Two questions about this sentence:
>
> 1. Why not "hearts",since it says "of all those..."?

Short answer: the *word* **heart** is not incorrect. Neither is **hearts**, *in certain usages.*

There is an idiom *to strike at the heart of some**thing**.* The meaning of this idiom is "[to damage something severely by attacking the most important part of *it.*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/strike-at-the-heart-of-sth)" EDIT: the idiom does not work here, as the idiom applies to inanimate objects, is a fixed phrase, and requires the singular *heart.* [Here's another dictionary definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/strike-at).

There is also a phrase in use: *to strike at the heart of some**one**.* Two examples in comments of the OP:

*Jesus strikes at the heart of those who need to forgive others and those who need to be forgiven.*  ([Source](http://www.christiansincommerce.org/christ-alive/lost-art-forgiveness-0))

*Brentlinger's insight strikes at the heart of those who decide to use scripture to harm, rather than to heal.* ([Source](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/44687787))

The meaning here is different from the idiom. The meaning is approximately *to deliver a blow at/to the heart of someone* or *to deeply affect someone.* The meaning can be gathered by a native speaker from the context. Frankly, I believe the construction of this phrase is a transferring of the idiom's wording *(strike at the heart of)* to a phrase involving people instead of inanimate objects.) Nevertheless, at this point, the meaning is not vital to the OP's question.[/EDIT]

And we are still left with the question of *Why not hearts?* And I come back to the answer that **either *heart* or *hearts* here is correct, depending on what the author wants to stress**.

The plural, or technically, the **distributive plural**, is the norm here. For example:

> New Short Film Depicts the **Lives** of Immigrant Women in the U.S. [(Source)](http://www.hispanicallyspeakingnews.com/latino-daily-news/details/new-short-film-depicts-the-lives-of-immigrant-women-in-the-u.s.-video/19025/)

Women is plural. Lives is plural. Nothing could be simpler. However, note the relative clause in this article's first sentence:

> ...a short film that tells the **story** of millions of immigrant women forced by inhumane U.S. immigration policy to choose...

Here, women is plural but *story* is singular.

The title uses lives the distributive plural, which is the norm. The relative clause uses the distributive singular, which can be used...

**when referring to *a shared experience.***

You can also use the singular at other times:

**When you refer to the *one* body part that all people have**

> He broke the nose of all those who he met.

The next examples are based on 10.47 of *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language:*

**When you want to focus on individual instances**

> We all have a good appetite.

**The singular is obligatory with some idioms.** The following idom should be familiar; notice that use of singular *heart* with plural *institutions:*

> Yesterday’s shootings struck at the heart of Canada’s governing institutions ([Source](http://www.newsmax.com/Newsfront/Canada-Ottawa-Parliament-attack/2014/10/22/id/602522/))

**To avoid ambiguity**

> Children must be accompanied by a parent. (Only one parent is needed.)

For further reference: 
*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language,* by Randoplh Quirck and others. [Section 10.47](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~flohaas/QuirkEtAl_755-71.pdf)

> > His classic tale of a poor orphan boy strikes at the **heart** of all those who have ever wanted "more", **as Oliver did**.
>
> 2. Which aforementioned action does "as Oliver did" refer to, "strikes" or "have ever wanted more"?

Oliver is closest to *have ever wanted more,* so that is what we expect.

And if we know that it is the character [Oliver Twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Twist_%28character%29) who gets into trouble for daring to *ask for more* gruel, then it is clear.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response and detailed answer. I googled and found sentences like "Jesus strikes at the heart of those who need to forgive others and those who need to be forgiven." ,"Brentlinger's insight strikes at the heart of those who decide to use scripture to harm, rather than to heal."...Please forgive me for my non-native poor English...The idiom it self is solid, but it's not proper to be used in this sentence. Dickens couldn't be devastating people who like Oliver Twist in the novel, could he?

Comment: Well, these are **two different things**. There is the idiom I linked to. It has a fixed meaning and applies to inanimate objects. The usages you have found do not share this meaning. Jesus is not going around devastating or severely damaging people who need forgiveness. Neither is Brentlinger's insight doing that. And *[The] classic tale of a poor orphan boy* is not *severely damaging/devastating* all those who have ever wanted "more".* The approximate meaning of *strike at the heart(s) of those who* is *deeply affect those who.*

Comment: Since there are grammatical, spelling and other errors throughout that article，as you said，would you please be kind enough to point out one or two of them for me？The article had been used as a teaching and testing material and it seems necessary to rectify the errors.

Comment: @dennylv I posted some corrections and suggestions [here](http://karamazov.livejournal.com/13759.html).  I apologize for the length of that post. Please leave any questions at that page as a comment. Let me know here if you have any difficulty accessing that page.

Comment: Thank you! I will have the pleasure of reading your post.

Answer (score 2):

1. They made a grammatical mistake.  It should be "at the hearts of all of those who have" or "at the heart of each of those who has."  (Good catch.)
2. There is a famous scene in [Oliver Twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Twist) where Oliver, a desperately poor orphan boy, asked for more food at a meal in his orphanage and was punished.  Oliver wanted more.

[Here is a link to a video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4iEdMMjqdA) of the famous scene (or one adaptation of it, anyway), if you're interested.

With regard to your question:

> No offend, however, actually I have googled several examples of using "strikes at the heart of those who", are they all putting it incorrectly?

My justification for the plural versus singular form of heart:
*Singular*:
My reading of the singular is that there is a collective goal or purpose that these people share that is being attacked by the tale of Oliver Twist.  This doesn't make sense in this context.  You could say something like, "Tighter international banking regulations strike at the heart of those people who finance international terrorism."  This would mean that the banking regulations damage the core operations of international terrorism financing.  It would not mean that each international terrorism financier's heart was being stricken.

*Plural*:
In the plural, I read the sentence as saying that each person's heart is stricken, that is, they are emotionally overwhelmed, by the tale of Oliver Twist.  This makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer to my second question is quite helpful. No offend, however, actually I have googled several examples of using "strikes at the heart of those who", are they all putting it incorrectly?

Comment: Polite criticism should never be offensive, though some people find it so.  I googled as well, and it seems as though using "heart" in place of "hearts" is a common mismatch.  The sentence is idiomatic ("Strike at the heart of something"), and it appears that people are extending that idiom to the plural without pluralizing "hearts" as expected.  I'm not enough of a grammarian to decide whether this is truly a grammatical mistake or if it is common enough to be considered proper English.  "Strike at the hearts" is not common at all, but other verbs ("Pull at the hearts," for instance") are.

Comment: So it may be kind of a rhetoric or flexible use for vividness, I guess.

Comment: @dennylv It may, or it may just be sloppy writing.  I'm honestly not sure.  We do both quite often.