# Are there execeptions to the rule that we always use singular forms to refer to singular objects and vice versa?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

If that was the case, those movies would not have been **successful**.

If that was the case, those movies would not have been **a success**.

If that was the case, those movies would not have been **successes**.

Do the third and second sentence mean the same thing as the first one?
When we refer to soemthing that's more than one, we use plurals. But are there exceptions? Like could I say all people live in a house, and mean all people live in separate houses?

Comment: There are exceptions to every "rule" of English that I have ever come across. Your third example is probably the rarest, but grammatically its fine, as long as they match the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two questions about this sentence: 1. Why not "hearts"? 2. Which aforementioned action does "as Oliver did" refer to?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/two-questions-about-this-sentence-1-why-not-hearts-2-which-aforementioned)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they mean the same thing. And yes exceptions exist like with the people and the houses.

While you forgot an A or something in a few parts the meaning comes across the same way.

The way I would put the people sentence;

> All the people live in houses.
>
> All the people live in separate houses.

I made houses plural in the first one is because it reaffirms that it means more than one building.

Answer (score 0):

If you said “everyone lives in a house”, it would be absurd to assume that everyone lives in *the same* house, so we will assume you meant “everyone lives in houses”.

This points to a general rule that you can say ambiguous things as long as *all possible meanings but one* are absurd. The exception (because every rule in English has an exception, including this rule) is that jokes often take advantage of this by making a discarded absurd meaning turn out to be the correct one.