# had flowers in their hands

Tags: singular-vs-plural

a. The demonstrators had a flower in their hands.
b. The demonstrators had a flower in their hand.
c. The demonstrators had flowers in their hand.

Which could be used if each had one flower in one hand?
Which could be used if some had more than one flower in one hand?
Which could be used if they had a flower in each hand?

Many thanks

Comment: There have been many questions on "multiple possession" - the general conclusion is that "English grammar is a bit of a mess" but "we seem to work out the meaning by context".

Comment: But in these examples it must be "in their hands" (many demonstrators, so one would assume there were many hands) or you must use the word "each" in some way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't remember anyone's names/name](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327134/i-cant-remember-anyones-names-name)

Answer (score 2):

Which could be used if each had one flower in one hand?

> The demonstrators had flowers in their hands.

Which could be used if some had more than one flower in one hand?

> The demonstrators had flowers in their hands.

Which could be used if they had a flower in each hand?

> The demonstrators had flowers in their hands.

Yes, those are all the same.  The meaning of that expression could cover all three situations.  You can use extra words to force just one meaning. But you'd never really need to. In this context all that really matters is that they were carrying flowers, not sticks or guns.

> Each protester was carrying one flower in one hand

> Each protestor was carrying one or more flowers in one hand.

> Each protestor was carrying two flowers, one in each hand.

All three of these are a bit ridiculous. They do express the exact meanings you asked for, but nobody talks like this.